Manejo de DataFrames con multi nivel de etiquetas de columnas
Disponemos del siguiente DataFrame
import pandas as pd

diccionario = {('Close', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 6.447411060333252,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 6.458560466766357,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 6.355827331542969},
 ('Close', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 15.645691871643066,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 15.576793670654297,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 15.184123992919922},
 ('Close', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 7.639999866485596,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 7.3585710525512695,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 7.617143154144287},
 ('Dividends', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('Dividends', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('Dividends', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('High', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 6.462173069917781,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 6.4950137941429835,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 6.484167138135582},
 ('High', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 15.71459112478325,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 15.672902540409932,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 15.623476283488671},
 ('High', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 7.961429119110107,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 7.6571431159973145,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 7.67285680770874},
 ('Low', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 6.398304652210158,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 6.424516927690275,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 6.3491993087984255},
 ('Low', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 15.583035171476382,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 15.515634345644942,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 15.136694094469423},
 ('Low', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 7.565713882446289,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 7.258571147918701,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 7.197143077850342},
 ('Open', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 6.4299375873533755,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 6.465188490738376,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 6.458559270675418},
 ('Open', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 15.65068439191203,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 15.65642665262451,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 15.623476283488671},
 ('Open', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 7.931428909301758,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 7.652856826782227,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 7.361429214477539},
 ('Stock Splits', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('Stock Splits', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('Stock Splits', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0},
 ('Volume', 'AAPL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 493729600,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 601904800,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 552160000},
 ('Volume', 'GOOGL'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 78169752,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 120067812,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 158988852},
 ('Volume', 'NFLX'): {pd.Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 17239600,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 23753100,
  pd.Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 23290400}}

datos = pd.DataFrame(diccionario)
datos 

¿Cómo puedo conseguir otro DataFrame 'aapl_df', de uno de los valores, por ejemplo, de 'AAPL', con solamente un nivel de etiquetas de columnas 'Close   Dividends   High    Low     Open    Stock Splits    Volume'?
He probado haciendo
# Seleccionamos las columnas correspondientes a 'AAPL'
aapl_df = datos['Close', 'Dividends', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Stock Splits', 'Volume']['AAPL']

# Ajustamos el índice para que coincida con las fechas originales
aapl_df = aapl_df.reset_index()

print(aapl_df)

Devuelve:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_30592/291253381.py in <module>
      1 # Seleccionamos las columnas correspondientes a 'AAPL'
----> 2 aapl_df = datos['Close', 'Dividends', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Stock Splits', 'Volume']['AAPL']
      3 
      4 # Ajustamos el índice para que coincida con las fechas originales
      5 aapl_df = aapl_df.reset_index()

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3502         if is_single_key:
   3503             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
-> 3504                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   3505             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506             if is_integer(indexer):

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_multilevel(self, key)
   3553     def _getitem_multilevel(self, key):
   3554         # self.columns is a MultiIndex
-> 3555         loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3556         if isinstance(loc, (slice, np.ndarray)):
   3557             new_columns = self.columns[loc]

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2872         keylen = len(key)
   2873         if self.nlevels < keylen:
-> 2874             raise KeyError(
   2875                 f"Key length ({keylen}) exceeds index depth ({self.nlevels})"
   2876             )

KeyError: 'Key length (7) exceeds index depth (2)'

También he probado haciendo:
# Seleccionamos las columnas correspondientes a 'AAPL'
aapl_df = datos.xs('AAPL', axis=1, level=1)

# Aplanamos el nivel de las etiquetas de las columnas
aapl_df.columns = aapl_df.columns.droplevel(1)

print(aapl_df)

Devuelve:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_30592/2953354365.py in <module>
      3 
      4 # Aplanamos el nivel de las etiquetas de las columnas
----> 5 aapl_df.columns = aapl_df.columns.droplevel(1)
      6 
      7 print(aapl_df)

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in droplevel(self, level)
   2067             level = [level]
   2068 
-> 2069         levnums = sorted(self._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level)[::-1]
   2070 
   2071         return self._drop_level_numbers(levnums)

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2067             level = [level]
   2068 
-> 2069         levnums = sorted(self._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level)[::-1]
   2070 
   2071         return self._drop_level_numbers(levnums)

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _get_level_number(self, level)
   1942 
   1943     def _get_level_number(self, level) -> int:
-> 1944         self._validate_index_level(level)
   1945         return 0
   1946 

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _validate_index_level(self, level)
   1933                 )
   1934             elif level > 0:
-> 1935                 raise IndexError(
   1936                     f"Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not {level + 1}"
   1937                 )

IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Agradeceré ayuda.

Si no he malinterpretado lo que buscas, el método xs() ya te retorna lo que buscas y es quizás lo más simple:
>>> datos.xs('AAPL', level=1,  axis=1)

               Close  Dividends      High       Low      Open  Stock Splits     Volume
2010-01-04  6.447411        0.0  6.462173  6.398305  6.429938           0.0  493729600
2010-01-05  6.458560        0.0  6.495014  6.424517  6.465188           0.0  601904800
2010-01-06  6.355827        0.0  6.484167  6.349199  6.458559           0.0  552160000

Observa que el error lo causa:
aapl_df.columns = aapl_df.columns.droplevel(1)

Y es que, como el error especifica, el dataframe que te retorna xs() solo tiene un nivel en las columnas. Esto se debe a que el propio método xs elimina por defecto el nivel al que pertenece la key (argumento drop_level es True por defecto):
>>> datos.xs('AAPL', level=1,  axis=1, drop_level=False)

               Close Dividends      High       Low      Open Stock Splits     Volume
                AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL         AAPL       AAPL
2010-01-04  6.447411       0.0  6.462173  6.398305  6.429938          0.0  493729600
2010-01-05  6.458560       0.0  6.495014  6.424517  6.465188          0.0  601904800
2010-01-06  6.355827       0.0  6.484167  6.349199  6.458559          0.0  552160000

Si especificas drop_level como False entonces si podrías aplicar  aapl_df.columns = aapl_df.columns.droplevel(1) o aapl_df.droplevel(1, axis=1), pero es más simple y eficiente hacerlo en la llamada a xs.

El primer intento falla porque al hacer:
datos['Close', 'Dividends', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Stock Splits', 'Volume']

Pandas interpreta cada clave en la lista de indices como un nivel distinto, para seleccionar una lista de columnas debes pasar un iterable:
datos[['Close', 'Dividends', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Stock Splits', 'Volume']]

En tu caso deberías pasar un iterable con las parejas con las dos claves correspondientes a cada nivel, por ejemplo:
>>> datos[[('Close', 'AAPL'), ('Dividends', 'AAPL')]]

               Close Dividends
                AAPL      AAPL
2010-01-04  6.447411       0.0
2010-01-05  6.458560       0.0
2010-01-06  6.355827       0.0

Pero es más simple (si ignoramos xs()) usar loc, por ejemplo:
>>> datos.loc[:, (slice(None), "AAPL")]

               Close Dividends      High       Low      Open Stock Splits     Volume
                AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL         AAPL       AAPL
2010-01-04  6.447411       0.0  6.462173  6.398305  6.429938          0.0  493729600
2010-01-05  6.458560       0.0  6.495014  6.424517  6.465188          0.0  601904800
2010-01-06  6.355827       0.0  6.484167  6.349199  6.458559          0.0  552160000

o usando pd.IndexSlice:
>>> datos.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, "AAPL"]]

               Close Dividends      High       Low      Open Stock Splits     Volume
                AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL      AAPL         AAPL       AAPL
2010-01-04  6.447411       0.0  6.462173  6.398305  6.429938          0.0  493729600
2010-01-05  6.458560       0.0  6.495014  6.424517  6.465188          0.0  601904800
2010-01-06  6.355827       0.0  6.484167  6.349199  6.458559          0.0  552160000

Si quieres solo algunas columnas del primer nivel:
>>> datos.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[["High", "Low"], "AAPL"]]

                High       Low
                AAPL      AAPL
2010-01-04  6.462173  6.398305
2010-01-05  6.495014  6.424517
2010-01-06  6.484167  6.349199

En estos casos si podrías usar droplevel() para eliminar el segundo nivel:
>>> datos.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[["High", "Low"], "AAPL"]].droplevel(1, axis=1)

                High       Low
2010-01-04  6.462173  6.398305
2010-01-05  6.495014  6.424517
2010-01-06  6.484167  6.349199

